# Issues running nightwatch + selenium on local docker pipelines

Tags: selenium, docker, nightwatch.js, bitbucket-pipelines

I am having issues when running a simple nightwatch test file on my local Docker image. I am trying to figure out why selenium does not want to run the local tests. If anyone has figured this out, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my test file:

> nw-example.test.js

```
module.exports = {
  'End-to-end all browsers' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .init('http://localhost:3000/')
      .setValue('#loginForm-username', '')
      .setValue('#loginForm-password', '')
      .pause(2000)
      .click('#loginForm-submit')
      .perform(function(done){
        console.log('Done testing')
        done()
      })
      .pause(3000)
      .assert.containsText('#app','Welcome,');
  }
};
```

Here is my nightwatch.json file:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./usr/local/bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "./usr/local/bin/geckodriver",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.safari.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost:3000",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName" : "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "marionette" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["headless", "--no-sandbox"]
        }
      }
    },

    "firefox" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox"
      }
    },

    "edge" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
      }
    },

    "safari" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "safari",
        "javascriptEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the errors I am getting:

```
root@2b755e5a6174:/vital-webapp/src/__tests__# nightwatch nw-example.test.js 

[Nw Example Test] Test Suite
================================

Running:  End-to-end all browsers
20:13:49.642 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@2465e6e1
20:13:49.643 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
20:13:49.646 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, javascriptEnabled: true, marionette: true, name: Nw Example Test}
20:13:49.646 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, javascriptEnabled: true, marionette: true, name: Nw Example Test} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 4516
Only local connections are allowed.
20:13:59.737 WARN - timeout
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
20:13:49.646 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, javascriptEnabled: true, marionette: true, name: Nw Example Test}
20:13:49.646 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, javascriptEnabled: true, marionette: true, name: Nw Example Test} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 4516
Only local connections are allowed.
20:13:59.737 WARN - timeout
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

While you configured *ChromeDriver* you have suplied the following  *desiredCapabilities* :

```
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName" : "chrome",
    "javascriptEnabled" : true,
    "marionette" : true,
    "acceptSslCerts" : true
  }
```

*ChromeDriver* have no such capability as **"marionette"** which is set to **true**.

Remove the *capability* **"marionette" : true** and execute your `@Test`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I removed the **"marionette"** capability but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Its really strange as I can get this running on my local machine with Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but unable to successfully do it on a Docker image.

Comment: Hi @matthewSerna Were you able to find a solution to this problem ?